# Mouse Cursor - for wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, cursor

I am currently using a plugin on my wordpress site (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cursor-trail/)

However I would perhaps like to rather use another method for the cursor trail, so that it looks like the cursor trail on this site (except with a meerkat):

Comment: You did not ask a question, you just stated what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this, you can use jQuery, as Tom suggested.

The code for this would be:

`

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

            //create img elements having pointer.png in their src 
            pointer = $('<img>').attr({'src':'pointer.png'});

            //and append them to document
            $(document.body).append(pointer); 

            //show them at mouse position & fade out slowly
            pointer.css({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    top: e.pageY +2 ,    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX +2   //offsets
                }).fadeOut(1500);   
});
});
```

`

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  Would I insert this at the top of the index file in wordpress, or inside a separate text file?